# How to show keyWindow in front of keyboard when app in background?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(self.backgroundImage)
```

I will try this one:

```
let windowCount = UIApplication.shared.windows.count

UIApplication.shared.windows[windowCount-1].addSubview(self.backgroundImage)
```

None

I type something with keyboard and press home buton. I need to show only background image when I return app but app shows keyboard in front of backgroundImage

Comment: Where are you showing the keyboard? It must be on some controller right?

Comment: @PGDev yes. It's view controller to show messenge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window contain keyboard is a single one and it's level is higher than the keyWindow. So your `self.backgroundImage` that in keyWindow can't cover keyboard.

Suggest:

*call `window.resignFirstResponder()` when app will enter background.*

Better way:

*Add your backgroundImage to keyboard window if it is showing*

```
if let keyboardWindow = applicationKeyboardWindow {
    keyboardWindow.addSubview(self.backgroundImage)
}

var applicationKeyboardWindow: UIWindow? {
   var windows = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter { win -> Bool in
        let descri = String(describing: type(of: win))
        return descri == "UITextEffectsWindow" || descri == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow"
    }
    windows.sort(by: { $0.windowLevel > $1.windowLevel } )
    return windows.first
}
```

Comment: How to do seconds way because the first way like window.endEditing(). I want after show background image, the keyboard keep its state before. Ex: App show/hide keyboard and press home -> return app -> show only background image -> show before view with show/hide keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `resignFirstResponder()` on the component (example: `UITextField/UITextView` ) for which you're showing the keyboard in `viewWillDisappear(_:)`, i.e.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.textField.endEditing(true)
}
```

In the above code, replace `self.textField` with the specific input element.

Comment: I try this way but I want after show background image, the keyboard keep its state before

Comment: What do you mean by keyboard keeps its state?

Comment: App show/hide keyboard and press home -> return app -> show only background image -> show before view with show/hide keyboard